# What is the term for a 'projection' into a higher dimensional space?

Tags: terminology, projection

> In mathematics, a **projection** is a mapping of a set (or other mathematical structure) into a subset (or sub-structure), which is equal to its square for mapping composition (or, in other words, which is idempotent). The restriction to a subspace of a projection is also called a projection, even if the idempotence property is lost.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(mathematics)

Is there a specific term for an analogous mapping from one space to a *higher* dimensional space?

Comment: Not exactly the same but have you thought of an embedding? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding

Comment: Have you read Wikipedia's [2D to 3D conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2D_to_3D_conversion) page? Not specifically math but might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Unprojection!

For an example of this usage, see: https://dondi.lmu.build/share/cg/unproject-explained.pdf